# Avoiding repeating expressions in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I give the expression `floor(grade/10)` a name and avoid repeating it in the following Oracle SQL query?

```
SELECT 10*floor(grade/10) left, 
       10*floor(grade/10) + 9 right, 
       count(*)
FROM Grades
WHERE grade IS NOT null
GROUP BY floor(grade/10)
ORDER BY floor(grade/10);
```

Comment: Assuming `grade` is non-negative, `10 * floor(grade / 10)` can be written more simply as `trunc(grade, -1)`. Then you may not feel the need to give it a name, since it's simple enough already. (That doesn't change the fact that the question, in general, is a good one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use CTE here -

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT floor(grade/10) grade
               FROM Grades
              WHERE grade IS NOT null)
SELECT 10 * grade left, 
       10 * grade + 9 right, 
       count(*)
  FROM CTE
 GROUP BY grade
 ORDER BY grade;
```

Comment: Although this is a fine solution for the given query, I do not like this solution for general use. Namely, should the query need to use another column from Grades, taking inner product would be necessary.

Comment: Please post that scenario. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: You are right. After looking for a more challenging scenario for a minute or so, I see that you will be able to use a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT x.left, x.left + 9 as right, 
       count(*)
FROM Grades g CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT 10*floor(g.grade/10) as left FROM DUAL) x
WHERE g.grade IS NOT null
GROUP BY x.left
ORDER BY x.left;
```

The advantage of lateral joins is twofold.  First, the `FROM` clause is a very reasonable place to define aliases.  Second, it makes it easier to chain calculations, when the chains depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the with clause (or subquery factoring):

```
with temp as
(select floor(grade/10) as some_value
   from grades
  where grade is not null)

select 10 * some_value as left,
       10 * some_value + 9 as right,
       count(*)
  from temp
 group by some_value
 order by some_value;
```

Comment: I wrote "some_value" here because I don't know what the value of floor(grade / 10) means.